# Langage D build on Windows package tinyredis-2.1.1 Error: undefined identifier `EWOULDBLOCK` dmd failed with exit code 1

Tags: windows, redis, d, dub

I'm trying to build a D project on my Windows machine. It works on mac but I have the following error when building in Windows, I use the command "dub" inside the project and get this at some point :

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\dub\packages\tinyredis-2.1.1\tinyredis\source\tinyredis\connection.d(145,30): Error: undefined identifier `EWOULDBLOCK`
dmd failed with exit code 1.
```

Any ideas why this EWOULDBLOCK variable is not recognized on Windows ?

Here is the part of connection.d where this identifier appears :

```
private :

void receive(TcpSocket conn, ref byte[] buffer)
{
    byte[1024 * 16] buff;
    size_t len = conn.receive(buff);

    if (conn.blocking)
    {
        if(len == 0)
            throw new ConnectionException("Server closed the connection!");
        else if(len == TcpSocket.ERROR)
            throw new ConnectionException("A socket error occurred!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (len == -1)
        {
            import core.stdc.errno;

            if (errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            {
                len = 0;
                errno = 0;
            }
            else
                throw new ConnectionException(format("A socket error occurred! errno: %s", errno));
        }
    }

    buffer ~= buff[0 .. len];
    debug(tinyredis) { writeln("Response : ", "'" ~ escape(cast(string)buffer) ~ "'", " Length : ", len); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a variable, it is a constant.

The simple answer is, it has [not](https://github.com/dlang/druntime/blob/master/src/core/stdc/errno.d#L124) been declared.

But looks to be 'required' as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5814770t.aspx) for compatibility purposes.

The problem is however, while MSVC's libc may support it, DMC's which is the default (-m32) probably won't. Either way this is a bug and should be reported to both the dependency and to D's bug [tracker](https://issues.dlang.org).

Answer (score 0):

EWOULDBLOCK is not defined on Windows (in core.stdc.errno), so you need to wrap that problematic part of code in a version block and handle the Windows properly. On Windows `core.sys.windows.winsock2` defines EWOULDBLOCK

However, the `std.socket` module has a helper function `wouldHaveBlocked()` that works on Windows as expected:

Something like the following would do:

```
if (wouldHaveBlocked()) {
  len = 0;
  errno = 0;
} else {
  throw new ConnectionException(format("A socket error occurred! errno: %s", errno));
}
```

Comment: I replace the part with EWOULDBLOCK in the connection.d of tinyredis package with your code, but wouldHaveBlocked() is not recognized : undefined identifier wouldHaveBlocked() . I am not sure i did what you expected me to do

Comment: If you carefully read the connection.d you will see that it uses selective import (it only imports TcpSocket from std.socket!) so naturally you will have undefined wouldHaveBlocked() ...